How to load TinyMce cloud editor in Wordpress with wp_editor()?
I would like to use the latest version of TinyMce on a frontend textarea. How can I load the cloud version 7 with wp_editor() not having conflicts with the already old implemented 4.9 one?
With this code I can use the cloud version but then I disable the rich textarea and bullet lists are stripped off. Therefore telling Wordpress not using 4.9 but 7 instead might be a better idea. But how?
function antipole_remove_rich_text() {    
return false;
}
add_filter('bp_xprofile_is_richtext_enabled_for_field', 'antipole_remove_rich_text');

